# Force testthat to ignore warnings

Tags: r, testthat

I have tests for a package that check functions that may or may not return warnings, for example:

```
test_that("test", {
  expect_true(is.na(log(NA)))
  expect_true(is.na(log(-1)))
})
```

I am **not** interested in checking weather the warnings appeared. Is there a way how I could tell `testthat` to **ignore** the warnings and not display them when running `devtools::test()`?

I know I could pack each function in `expect_warning`, or `suppressWarnings`, but instead I'd like to do something like

```
test_that("test", {  
  ignoreAllTheWarningsInside({
     expect_true(is.na(log(NA)))
     expect_true(is.na(log(-1)))
  })
})
```

Unfortunately `options(warn = -1)` also does not seem to work for this.

Comment: I used the following workaround: `expect_warning(a <- is.na(log(NA)))` and `expect_true(a); ...`

Comment: @Christoph I usually use `expect_warning(expect_true(is.na(log(-1))))`, but the problem is as above: for some functions there will be warnings and for some will not, so I am *not* expecting warnings for each case. Moreover, I would like not to have to pack each function in `suppressWarnings()`, since it's lots of copy-and-pasting.

Comment: I use `a <- ...` if I want to be able to do several tests on `a` (Just as explanation). But I agree, that handling of warnings is sometimes strange. Do you use `RSudio`? Could it be a problem with `RStudio`? To be honest, I never checked that...

Comment: `options(warn = -1)` works for me.

Comment: Are you sure that using suppressWarnings like `suppressWarnings({expect_true(is.na(log(NA))); expect_true(is.na(log(-1)))})` does not work ?

Comment: @KarlForner the question was asked almost 5 years ago, It's hard to comment on it right now.

Comment: Oh I had not realized it was old. It's still in the list of unanswered questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `suppressWarnings()` around your script should do the trick.  These examples show where you can use the function within your tests.  No need for a custom function as all warnings will be silenced.

```r
testthat::test_that("no suppression", {
  testthat::expect_true({
    warning()
    TRUE
  })
})
#> -- Warning (<text>:2:3): no suppression ----------------------------------------
#> 
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. testthat::expect_true(...)
#>  2. testthat::quasi_label(enquo(object), label, arg = "object")
#>  3. rlang::eval_bare(expr, quo_get_env(quo))

testthat::test_that("suppress inside", {
  testthat::expect_true(
    suppressWarnings({
      warning()
      warning()
      TRUE
    })
  )
})
#> Test passed

testthat::test_that("suppress outside", {
  suppressWarnings(
    testthat::expect_true({
      warning()
      warning()
      TRUE
    })
  )
})
#> Test passed
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: As far as I remember it didn't work when writing the question but does now, so I'm accepting the answer.